# Collecting page data ...TypeError: 'ownKeys' on proxy: trap returned extra keys but proxy target is non-extensible at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, proxy, prisma, next.js13

Everything is working fine as I expected but when I tried to run 'npm run build' that proxy error occurred. The whole error is like this
`Collecting page data  ...TypeError: 'ownKeys' on proxy: trap returned extra keys but proxy target is non-extensible
at Function.freeze ()
at 17716 (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/app/api/expressSearch/route.js:1:1653)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
at 97628 (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/app/api/expressSearch/route.js:1:428)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:146)
at **webpack_exec** (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/app/api/expressSearch/route.js:1:1749)
at /Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/app/api/expressSearch/route.js:1:1777
at **webpack_require**.X (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:1638)
at /Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/app/api/expressSearch/route.js:1:1762
at Object. (/Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/.next/server/app/api/expressSearch/route.js:1:1820)

> Build error occurred
> Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/expressSearch
> at /Users/philipbright/Downloads/MyWayTravel&Tour/template/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> type: 'Error'
> }
> Collecting page data  .%

it shows different files with this error every time i run build but only from my api folders this is my api/expressSearch

```
import { NextApiResponse } from 'next';
```

import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const POST = async (request: any, response: NextApiResponse) => {
try {

```
const body = request.body;

const { from, to, departureDate, returnDate } = body;

const departureDay = new Date(departureDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });
const returnDay = new Date(returnDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });

const searchData = await prisma.express.findMany({
  where: {
    departureRegion: from,
    arrivalRegion: to,
    AND: [
      {
        activeDays: {
          has: departureDay,
        },
      },
      {
        activeDays: {
          has: returnDay,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});

return response.status(200).json(searchData);
```

} catch (err) {
return response.status(500).json({ message: "Express Post Error",  error: (err as Error).message, });
}
};